# How to prevent a d3.geo map to pan, but keep zoom

Tags: d3.js

Using a d3 map like this one: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5593150

I would like the map to stay centered on the same spot.

is it possible to de-activate the pan, but keep the zoom active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply ignore any translation in the handler function. The only difficulty is to set the translation such that the center point is the same for different zoom levels (i.e. set the zoom on the projection first):

```
projection
  .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI);
var tiles = tile
  .scale(zoom.scale())
  .translate(projection([-74.0064, 40.7142]).map(function(x) { return -x; }))
  ();
```

Complete demo [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8a38501d9f1bdc9a81ae).